# How do I get PyCharm to autocomplete

Tags: python, pycharm, unreal

I am trying to write Unreal scripts in PyCharm. Currently, I wish to use the autocomplete feature, and I have already loaded in the pip files and added the stub into the interpreter paths, and I've typed into the idea.properties file.
idea.max.intellisense.filesize = 50000

However, when I type in PyCharm "unreal.", I get a dropdown that shows "if, ifn, ifnn, main, etc" (see picture) instead of the Unreal methods. What should I be doing to get the proper drop down?

[image]

Comment: Is `unreal` an installed module? Have you overwritten that with another file/variable of the same name?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the correct Python interpreter selected and
go to `File` > `Settings` > `Project: <your_project_name>` > `Python Interpreter`.


Enable autocompletion for Unreal Engine:
Go to `File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `General` > `Auto Import`, and under the `Exclude from Import and Completion` section, make sure that the "unreal" package is not excluded.


You can also try manually invalidating the caches and restarting PyCharm. To do this, go to `File` > `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` and choose "Invalidate and Restart."


Also check your Code Insight settings:
Go to `File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `General` > `Code Completion` Ensure that "Autopopup code completion" and "Show suggestions as you type" are enabled.

Comment: Also make sure that indexing is finished

Comment: I don't have a "Exclude from Import and Completion"